# Por que no funciona esta comprobación de multiselect vacío

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de hacer una comprobación si dos campos `multiselect` están vacíos , Si están ambos llenos ejecute una parte de código, pero **`siempre me dice que están llenos.`**

**JS**

```
function ComprobarTallyColor() {
  if($("#colores").val().length >= 0 && $("#tallas").val().length >= 0){ 
    $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error<br /> Talla o Color vacios', sticky : false, type : 'notice' }); 
   } else {
     $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error<br /> Talla o Color llenos', sticky : false, type : 'notice' }); 
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select onchange="ComprobarTallyColor()" name="tallas[]" id="tallas" style="width: 410px;" class="multibuskiselect multibuskiselect_Inarticulos" multiple="multiple">
<?php foreach($CTallas as $DTallas) { ?><option value="<?=$DTallas["id"];?>"><?=$DTallas["1"];?></option><?php } ?></select>


<label>Colores:</label></td>
<select onchange="ComprobarTallyColor()" id="colores" name="colores[]" style="width: 410px;" class="multibuskiselect multibuskiselect_Inarticulos" multiple="multiple">
<?php foreach($CColores as $DColores) { ?><option value="<?=$DColores["id"];?>"><?=$DColores["1"];?></option><?php } ?></select>
```

Comment: Como menciona @Aponcedeleonch , los `if` están invertidos,  como punto importante si no hay opciones seleccionadas en un `select` la función `val()` retornará `null` por lo tanto no tendrá una propiedad `length` y tendrá un error ahí.

Comment: @Dev.Joel A ultima hora los cambie a ver si cambiaba el mensaje que daba. pero siempre es el mismo. y se ve que los puse invertidos aquí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final quitando el = funciona 
así que ha quedado así:

```
if($("#colores").val().length > 0 && $("#tallas").val().length > 0){
```

:) Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco difícil de ver por como tienes el código de JS pero en primera instancia me parece que el problema es que tienes al revés el mensaje del `if` y el `else`. Donde debería decir llenos dice vacíos y viceversa.

Si no es eso posiblemente sea cosa de cómo estás tratando de obtener el número de opciones en tu select. Posiblemente usando algo como lo siguiente sea lo más apropiado

```
$('#colores option').size()
```

Y entonces tu if quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
if($('#colores option').size() >= 0 && $('#tallas option').size() >= 0){ 
    $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error<br /> Talla y Color llenos', sticky : false, type : 'notice' });
} else { 
    $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error<br /> Talla o     Colores vacios', sticky : false, type : 'notice' }); 
}
```

De nuevo, puede ser que tu código funcione y sólo sea cosa de lo que estás imprimiendo en el `if`.

EDICIÓN

Ya vi que pusiste mejor tu código de JS. Sí tienes al revés los mensajes. En el `if` compruebas que los dos estén llenos o tengan algo y sin embargo estás imprimiendo `'Error<br /> Talla o Color vacios'`

Comment: Poniéndolo así no responde ningún mensaje :_( ni de lleno ni vacío es un select multiple no se si será importante

Comment: Por lo que veo .size fue abandonado en jQuery 1.8 :_(